# IE 9 authentication cookie issue

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-9, iis-7.5, forms-authentication, windows-server-2008-r2

Forms authentication cookie is randomly cleared in HTTP requests and users redirected to Login page. Random logout cause (cookie cleared) is revealed in the IIS cookie log.

Since it is not occurring in any pattern and it is very random (once in 15 days for 3 users randomly) , we could not find exactly where it got cleared whether it is cleared by the web browser or cleared in one of the network component or it is cleared in the load balancer or cookie cleared in the previous response.

Note: We troubleshooted and confirmed that the following are not the cause
1) Application pool recycle
2) Load balancer session affinity

It is an intranet application running on IIS 7.5/Windows server 2008 R2 and browser is IE 9 on windows 7 64 bit.

If anyone having/had this similar issue then please share your experience and thoughts. Thanks in advance.